# eas update is not working properly for my project

Tags: android, react-native, expo, ota, eas

I am using eas build and update in my expo app, followed the docs for the implementation and everything was working fine. But I just tested it yesterday and it is not working now.

But what I realised is that, when I refresh the app 2 times (as mentioned in docs), it doesn't download any new updates but if I do it multiple times (nearly 5 times), though the update works on that particular refresh but the assets (images and icons) are gone.

And if I refresh the app again, then the update is gone and assets are back, like it reverts back to older update (which is actually the build itself).

Right now, i am using app.config.js as well as app.json (i need app.json for google ads as that is not reading the config from app.config.js).

Here are the config files;

**app.config.js**

```
import "dotenv/config";

export default {
  expo: {
    backgroundColor: "#1A1A1A",
    owner: "owner",
    name: "name",
    slug: "slug",
    version: "1.0.0",
    assetBundlePatterns: ["**/*"],
    extra: {
      eas: {
        projectId: "<project id>",
      },
      ...
    },
    runtimeVersion: "1.0.1", // changed the runtime version from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1 as i thought this may be the reason
    updates: {
      url: "https://u.expo.dev/<project id>",
    },
    android: {
      ...,
    },
    
  },
};
```

**app.json**

```
{
  "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-****************" // my google ads id
  }
}
```

**androidManifest.xml**

```
<meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL" android:value="https://u.expo.dev/<project id>"/>
<meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.ENABLED" android:value="true"/>
<meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_CHECK_ON_LAUNCH" android:value="ALWAYS"/>
<meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_LAUNCH_WAIT_MS" android:value="0"/>
<meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_RUNTIME_VERSION" android:value="1.0.1"/>
```

I think this is the only relevant code to eas and eas updates.

Any help is greatly appretiated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using this code to access env variables;

In my app.config.js, inside the `extra` object;

```
extra: {
   BASE_URL: process.env.BASE_URL

}
```

This will load the `BASE_URL` from .env during build.

Now to access it in my code, I was using;

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants'

const baseUrl = Constants.manifest.extra.BASE_URL
```

The problem lies in `Constants.manifest`, it gets undefined after we send an update this `extra` in that case is undefined, breaking the app. And if the app breaks due to an update, eas rolls back to the previous update.

To fix it, use  `Constants.expoConfig.extra.BASE_URL`.

One more thing to note is, while sending an update, we also need to upload the env variables with the new update too, which is done like this;

```
BASE_URL=https://example.com ANOTHER_VAR=some_value eas update --branch preview --message "some message"
```