# EAS update breaks app & assets do not load

Tags: android, react-native, expo, ota, eas

I am using expo to build an app & recently I tried to send updates using eas update. I followed the [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/eas-update/getting-started/) on sending updates however when I receive the update the views & texts I added were loading up for e.g. I added a text "update version" which was not in the first build but after receiving the update the text was showing but the images & icons did not load which were already present in the build (I did not send them by update). After reloading the app it rolls back & goes back to the previous version which is the build itself.

I did my research but I was not able to figure out why I was facing this issue.

I found this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75078402/eas-update-is-not-working-properly-for-my-project) which had the exact same issue, I followed what was mentioned in the solution but still the error persisted.

Here are the config files.

**eas.json**

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.7.2"
  },
  "build": {
    "development":{
      "env":{
        "FIREBASE_ENV":"dev"
      },
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      },
      "channel":"development"
    },
    "production": {
      "env":{
        "FIREBASE_ENV":"prod"
      },
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      },
      "channel":"production"
    },
    "development-client": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      },
      "channel":"development"
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

**app.json**

```
{
    "expo": {
      "name": "Bento",
      "slug": "bento",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "orientation": "portrait",
      "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
      "splash": {
        "image": "./assets/splash.png",
        "resizeMode": "cover",
        "backgroundColor": "#131212"
      },
      "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
      "ios": {
        "supportsTablet": true
      },
      "android": {
        "adaptiveIcon": {
          "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
          "backgroundColor": "#131212"
        },
        "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
        "package": <package name>
      },
      "web": {
        "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
      },
      "plugins": [
        "@react-native-firebase/app",
        "@react-native-firebase/auth",
        "@react-native-firebase/perf",
        "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics"
      ]
    }
  }
```

app.config.js

```
module.exports = ({ config }) => {
  return {
    ...config,
    extra: {
      firebaseEnv: process.env.FIREBASE_ENV,
      eas: {
        projectId: <project-id>
      }
    },
    updates: {
      url: "https://u.expo.dev/<project-id>"
    },
    runtimeVersion: {
      policy: "sdkVersion"
    },
  };
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "bento",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "expo",
    "template",
    "nativebase"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start:development": "SET FIREBASE_ENV=dev&&expo start --dev-client",
    "start:production": "set FIREBASE_ENV=prod&&expo start --dev-client",
    "build:dev-client": "eas build --profile development-client --platform android",
    "build:development": "eas build --profile development --platform android ",
    "build:production": "eas build --profile production --platform android",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "start": "expo start --dev-client"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/poppins": "^0.2.3",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.7",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.3.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^17.3.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^17.3.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^17.3.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/in-app-messaging": "^17.3.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^17.3.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/perf": "^17.3.2",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^9.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "expo": "~48.0.6",
    "expo-constants": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.1.5",
    "expo-device": "~5.2.1",
    "expo-font": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.18.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "native-base": "3.4.0",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.3",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.11",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7",
    "expo-updates": "~0.16.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.8"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Does your project has eas.json file?
also, does your app.json has these code?

    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "expo-code-here"
      }
    }

Comment: Yes as you can see in app.config.js . I have both these values. Yes i also have eas.json

Comment: I have the same issue - did you mange to fix this?

Comment: @neeko not yet. Although i have raised an issue in eas Github page. For now i just create new build & distribute it.

Answer (score 0):

Try These steps:

1. `expo login` (then login using expo username and password)
2. `eas build:configure`
3. Go to esa.json and copy-paste

```
 {
          "cli": {
            "version": ">= 3.2.1" //<--- ** make sure cli version matches with you projects cli
          },
          "build": {
            "development": {
              "developmentClient": true,
              "distribution": "internal",
              "ios": {
                "buildConfiguration": "Release",
                "image": "latest"
              }
            },
            "preview": {
              "distribution": "internal",
              "android": {
                "buildType": "apk"
              },
              "ios": {
                "simulator": true
              }
            },
            "production": {
              "ios": {
                "buildConfiguration": "Release",
                "image": "latest"
              }
            }
          },
          "submit": {
            "production": {}
          }
        }
```

4. Then Try `eas update`

Comment: I already have this file. I have edited my question you can see it now. The updates are sending but upon recieving them they break the app. There is no issue in creating updates or publishing them

Comment: Please read my question again. The issue is not that I am not able to send updates but upon recieving them the app does not load images & fonts & after reloading it goes to back to its previous version that is the build itself.